# "Please confirm immediately'' vs ''Please confirm at your earliest convenience''

Tags: phrase-meaning, difference, writing

I took a test about choosing the appropriate salutation in writing a business letter. The question tells:

> "If you want someone to act immediately, you can write:..."?

I answered:

> "Please confirm immediately"

but it turned out to be wrong.

> "Please confirm at your earliest convenience"

was the correct choice. I'm confused why is it that even if I want someone to ACT IMMEDIATELY, I should still write: "at your earliest convenience"?

Comment: This is unclear to me. Please [edit] the question to include the actual text of the question you tried to answer and exactly what you said that you were told was incorrect.

Comment: Maybe the answer was marked incorrect because asking someone to do something  'immediately' will be perceived as an order, and thus rude, whereas 'at your earliest convenience' is a polite request? Is this from a business English course or lesson?

Comment: I agree with what @MichaelHarvey said.

Comment: yes, for business letter.

Comment: "at your earliest convenience' is the standard military, particularly naval phrase meaning "Drop anything else and do this right now, or better yet, yesterday" It is polite in form,. but carries the connotation of "get your rear moving".It is if anything less polite in practice than a simple "immediately". In particular "my office at your  earliest convenience" means "get here right away" and may well imply "you are in hot water". For anyone who has served, or knows one who has, it carres significant weight.

Comment: @Michael Harvey
 The phrase "at your earliest convenience" is **always** addressed from a superior to a subordinate, it is in fact an **order**..

Comment: Hello EnglishLearner and welcome to ELL! This looks like it might be a good question if you can add the exact words of the question. That is why the question was closed. I'll be happy to reopen it and maybe even answer it myself if you can improve it

Comment: @DavidSiegel - not in UK business communications. I could write to the Lord Chief Justice requesting certain information and say that I would be grateful for a reply 'at his earliest convenience'. - 1832 letter by Charles Dickens: “You will perhaps oblige me with a line at your earliest convenience.”

Comment: @Michael Harvey
 Really? It seems different communities use the phrase differently then. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @DavidSiegel - I am not aware of any such convention in the UK military, although I can certainly imagine an NCO using a parody of polite address as a sarcastic way of rebuking a subordinate for tardiness , e.g. Private Harvey! I hope you will forgive me for intruding on your doubtless busy schedule to enquire whether you are able to see your way clear to GETTING YOUR F*****G BACKSIDE IN THAT TRUCK?

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is fine *if there is no other context missing*. In that case, the person who designed the test has made the mistake.

This appears to be a case of bad test writing. It's a common problem we see on this site, where the person creating the test has one particular answer in mind, but phrases a question poorly, so that more than one correct answer is possible, and confused students come here asking for an explanation.

Now, if the wording included "polite" or "to a superior" or "using the business writing phrases we have learned this week", then your answer is wrong.

There are so many possible answers in that blank that it seems quite odd to put it in a test question.

"Please confirm..."

- immediately
- as soon as possible
- right away
- the moment you get this
- at your earliest convenience

All those are correct answers. In fact, the last one is the weakest, because it suggests the other person's convenience, depending on who is receiving the letter.